# Using Template Blocks in Combination with Template Functions in Golang

Tags: templates, go

I'm looking to use template blocks in Golang to get a "template inheritance" style overwrite logic.

I have a `base.html` template which is something like this:

```
<title>{{block "title" .}}Default Title{{end}}</title>
<body>{{block "content" .}}This is the default body.{{end}}</body>
```

And then I have a template `blogpost.html` like so:

```
{{define "title"}}Blog Post Title{{end}}
{{define "content"}}Lorem Ipsum...{{end}}
```

All of this works flawlessly as long as I just use `ParseFiles` and then execute the template

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles("./templates/base.html", "./templates/blogpost.html")
t.Execute(t, viewModel)
```

The way I did it was calling `ParseFiles` once for every template I needed to render. E. g. I did not call templates by name.

However, I now want to also use Template Functions. Now I need to call `template.New` to get an empty template, assign a name, add the template functions and parse the files (`Funcs` "[must be called before the template is parsed](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs)") :

```
tpl := template.Must(
    template.New("somename").Funcs(sprig.FuncMap()).ParseGlob("*.html")
)
```

This seems to be incompatible with my idea of template inheritance. I have to `ExecTemplate`with my `base.html` as a parameter in order to get any output. However, I'd like to load *one* base template and many content templates. Then call the content templates by name.

Am I misunderstanding the way that Golang templates and/or Blocks are intended to be used? What's an elegant and idiomatic way to perform this kind of task?

Comment: Yeah... I had to write my own package to solve this issue [https://github.com/biz/templates](https://github.com/biz/templates). The package creates a template per "view" that has access to any "partial" that is defined. There is also support for funcs that get added to all of the templates.

Comment: Calling `t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "foo", data)` will execute only the `foo` template and the templates that `foo` explicitly invokes. It will not execute the rest of the templates in `t`'s parse.Tree. You can use one template instance per "page" and call `Execute` instead of `ExecuteTemplate`.

Comment: @mkopriva this technique won't work if you want to redefine a `block` in multiple templates.

Comment: @jmaloney that's why I wrote "one template instance per page", i.e. each instance would parse its own redefinition of the base block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to add template functions to what you already have working:

```
t, err := template.New("base.html").Funcs(sprig.FuncMap()).ParseFiles("./templates/base.html", "./templates/blogpost.html")
```